# Creating a custom entity with the Entity framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

If I have for example two entities, lets say Customers and Staff with no relation between them, is it possible to create a third entity which doesn't have a corresponding table in the database which takes some information from the first and the second entity and also one or two additional columns (for example computed columns)?

Comment: Well, yes. You'll need to find a relation someway (you can also have computed properties in an entity class, just don't put any setter and it won't be present in db). Just be conscient you won't be able to use that custom class (or these "unsettable properties" in linq2entites statements.

Comment: You work Database, Model or Code First?

Comment: So is it possible if tables have relationship. I used partial classes to extend entities. But a custom entity would be much of help for a lot of scenarios

Answer (score 0):

You can join entities through this: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/simonince/archive/2009/03/23/mapping-two-tables-to-one-entity-in-the-entity-framework.aspx

But I do believe they have to be related; otherwise, how would it know what information was correctly tied to each other?  The only thing it could do is query all rows of one entity and match them up with all rows of the other, which is probably not what's desired.